# How to make a link that takes you back from https to http?

Tags: playframework

I have this link on my page (page1):

```
<a href="@{Controller.action1().secure()}">Link1</a>
```

that takes me to a page (page2) over https. How to make a link on page2 that takes me back from https to http? I thought @@ notation would do the trick:

```
<a href="@@{Controller.action2()}">Link2</a>
```

but it doesn't, action2 also gets called via https.

Comment: What does your generated HTML look like?  If your links don't include protocols, maybe you could add the prefix `http://` by hand.

Comment: @XavierHolt thanks, I tried this and it works. I was under the wrong impression that `@@{...}` always gave full `http://` path. If I use `@{...}` (which gives relative path) instead of `@@{...}` I can manually set `http://`. Not elegant, but works. Alexander Ponomarenko's answer, on the other hand, looks like a robust solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play doesn't have a method that would be opposite to secure(), but you can implement it yourself with custom JavaExtension:

```
import play.templates.JavaExtensions;
import play.mvc.Router.ActionDefinition;

public class MyExtensions extends play.templates.JavaExtensions {

    public static String unsecure(ActionDefinition action) {
            if (!action.url.contains("http://") && !action.url.contains("https://")) {
                action.absolute();
            }
            action.url = action.url.replace("https:", "http:");
            return action.url;
        }
```

Custom extension methods should return `String`, and the parameter will hold the enhanced object, [as the documentation suggests](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/templates#Createcustomextensions). The code is almost identical to the [secure method's code](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/mvc/Router.java).

With this method you can now use:

```
href="@{Controller.action2().unsecure()}"
```

Comment: Great! Works like a charm! The only thing left to fix now is to make secure() and unsecure() methods change not only protocol, but also the port according to application.conf. There is a ticket raised for that bug ([ticket](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/362-using-secure-does-not-change-port-when-reverse-routing)) but I don't know why it hasn't been addressed yet.